# Google Spreadsheets API saying that .save() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I'm working with a spreadsheet in Node.js using google-spreadsheet-api. I'm trying to update the values to the spreadsheet after updating them in code with `.save()`, as directed in the documentation, but I'm getting this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data[i][5].save is not a function
```

Here is the code I'm using. I've removed the extraneous code regarding initializing the doc and all that:

```
          await doc.loadInfo();
          sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
          data = await sheet.getRows().then((q) => {
            return q.map((v) => v._rawData);
          });
          console.log(data)

          voterID = message.author.id //discord.js, gets id of the person triggering this function

          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //go through every row of voting candidate
            if (data[i][5].includes(voterID)) { //if user already their ID "signature" voted on something else
              data[i][5].replace(`${voterID}, `, "") // remove it
            }

            data[earned - 1] += `${voterID}, ` //add their signature to the voting candidate they specified 

            await data[i][5].save();
            await data[earned - 1].save();
          }
        }
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong here.
Edit: Forgot to mention that I *did* try updating the package, nothing changed.

Comment: May I ask where you take the documentation from? I'm asking because the npm package you mentioned is not Google Sheet's official and might not follow the documentation properly. `npm install googleapis@39 --save` is the official package install command

Comment: [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) is the official node.js quickstart

Comment: [This is the API I'm using. It includes a save function that my compiler isn't recognizing.](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/)

Comment: Not familiar with that library but from the docs you linked it looks like every time `save` is called it is on something in this format `row[i].save()`. Yet you are calling `data[i][j].save()`. Maybe try not saving in such a granular way and just save `data[i].save()`. Or even just use what looks like a save all method `sheet.saveUpdatedCells(); // save all updates in one call` - since by "save" I suppose it means "send a request" and it is generally better to send less requests.